# my application doesnt run on IE browser, i have abp-zero-template 6.5.0 and angular vesrion 7.1.0

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

i am running the application on IE 11 , but my application giving syntax erros in console. in scripts.js and vendor.js

**Error** :

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the polyfills file, whether you have uncommented the related import for IE browser.

The polyfills file content like this:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/**
 * If the application will be indexed by Google Search, the following is required.
 * Googlebot uses a renderer based on Chrome 41.
 * https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/rendering
 **/
//import 'core-js/es6/array';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
//import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 **/
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

From the screenshot, it seems that you are using Arrow function expression, as we all known, the [arrow function expression not support IE browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Please try to use the [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl) translate it to ES5.

Besides, you could also try to install the [babel bolyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) in your angular application.

Comment: thanks for your reply , can you please explain how can i install babel polyfill and use it in my angular application.

Comment: You could refer to [this article](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) and [this blog](https://medium.com/@hubert.zub/using-babel-7-and-preset-typescript-to-compile-angular-6-app-448eb1880f2c) to use it. But, I think the easiest method is using the [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl) translate it to ES5

Comment: hello, i tried adding suggested package and another below packages
+ @babel/preset-typescript@7.7.2
+ @babel/core@7.7.2
+ @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.7.0
+ @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators@7.7.0
+ @babel/preset-env@7.7.1

Comment: now getting different errors such as , 

HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
localhost:4200
HTML1201: localhost is a website you've added to Compatibility View.
localhost:4200
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number
polyfills.js (7887,5)
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'bind'
runtime.js (209,11)
SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier
styles.js (622,24)
SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier
scripts.js (16,10596)
SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier
vendor.js (2376,23)
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number
main.js (12602,5)

Comment: Please check the polyfills file, whether you have uncommented the related import for IE browser. In the index.html header tag try to add the "<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">" tag.

Comment: hello, i am still getting same error , can you please help me to get this working in IE.

Comment: arrow function error or babel error? I have modified the reply, please check the polyfill file and uncomment the related import. For the original error, you could try to use the [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl) translate the related code to ES5.

Comment: Besides, about the use of Babel and the Babel plugin `@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions`, you could check [this article](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/usage) and using the following command to use the plugin-transform-arrow-functions plugin: `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions

./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-dir lib --plugins=@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions`

Comment: i checked my polyfills file it look fine. i installed plugin also. still getting arrow functions error

Comment: Try to use the [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl) translate the related code to ES5, then replace the original code. after that, try to clear the browser cache.